# Avoiding duplicate results mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, distinct

I'm creating a commenting system with reply functionality and I've seen to run into an issue.

**Comments table**

```
id        post_id        comment          replyTo

0           17            Blah               2

1           17            hello              2

2           17            goodbye         

3           17            great              1

4           17            bad
```

**My code**

```
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE post_id='$post_id' ORDER BY id DESC");

while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments))
{
    $id = $comment['id'];

    $comment = $comment['comment'];

    $reply = $comment['replyTo'];

    echo $comment;

    echo "<br />";


    $replyQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE replyTo='$id' ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments))

    {

        $id = $comment['id'];

        $comment = $comment['comment'];

        $reply = $comment['replyTo'];

        echo $comment;

        echo "<br />";

     }

}
```

**My result**

```
Blah

great

hello

goodbye

      blah

      hello

great

bad
```

**intended result**

```
goodbye

      blah

      hello

      great

bad
```

**THANKS!!!!!**

Comment: What's the default value of replyTo? E.g. where id is 2. Is it null? What's the type of this field? Why didn't you post the complete table structure?

Comment: 2 and 4 are both null so those posts are not replying to anyone. They're initial posts.

Comment: BTW, the mysql_* functions are obsolete and should not be used any more. Please consider using PDO or mysqli_* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS id,GROUP_CONCAT(post_id) AS     post_id,GROUP_CONCAT(comment) AS comment,GROUP_CONCAT(date) AS date,GROUP_CONCAT(submittedBy)  AS submittedBy,GROUP_CONCAT(replyTo) AS replyTo FROM comment WHERE post_id='$post_id' GROUP BY replyTo ORDER BY id DESC");
while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments))
{
$cid = $comment['id'];
$comment_submit = $comment['submittedBy'];
$submitted_comment = $comment['comment'];
$comment_date = $comment['date'];
$replyTo = $comment['replyTo'];

echo'<div id="c'.$id.'" class="comment_container">';
    echo'<div class="comment_header">';
        echo'<a href="#" class="report">Flag</a>';
        echo'<a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a>';
        echo'<span>';
        echo $comment_submit.' - '.$comment_date.'</span>';
    echo'</div>';
    echo'<p>';
        echo $submitted_comment;
    echo'</p>';
    echo'
    <form method="post" class="replyForm">
        <textarea name="post_data_comment" class="replyTextArea" placeholder="@'.$comment_submit.'"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'.$post_id.'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="replyTo" value="'.$cid.'" />
        <div class="row_three">
            <span class="char_left_reply">Characters left: <span>500</span></span>
            <input type="button" value="Reply" name="share_reply" class="reply_comment" />
        </div>
    </form>
    ';
echo'</div>';

$reply = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE replyTo='$cid' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($replies = mysql_fetch_assoc($reply))
{
    $id = $replies['id'];
    $comment_submit = $replies['submittedBy'];
    $submitted_comment = $replies['comment'];
    $comment_date = $replies['date'];
    $replyTo = $replies['replyTo'];

    echo'<div id="c'.$id.'" class="comment_container" style="width:90%; float:right" >';
        echo'<div class="comment_header">';
            echo'<a href="#" class="report">Flag</a>';
            echo'<a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a>';
            echo'<span>';
            echo $comment_submit.' - '.$comment_date.'</span>';
        echo'</div>';
        echo'<p>';
            echo $submitted_comment;
        echo'</p>';
        echo'
        <form method="post" class="replyForm">
            <textarea name="post_data_comment" class="replyTextArea" placeholder="@'.$comment_submit.'"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="'.$post_id.'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="replyTo" value="'.$cid.'" />
            <div class="row_three">
                <span class="char_left_reply">Characters left: <span>500</span></span>
                <input type="button" value="Reply" name="share_reply" class="reply_comment" />
            </div>
        </form>
        ';
    echo'</div>';
}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

The first line should read:

```
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE post_id='$post_id' AND replyTo IS NULL ORDER BY id DESC");
```

so that only the top-level comments are included.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried a similar method such as replyTo='' however it doesn't display all the results.

Comment: You need to make sure the condition is executed only for the top-level comments. You also have a naming conflict, which I didn't notice in the first place. The variables you create in the outer loop are overwritten in the inner loop. Please make sure the inner loop does not modify the variable $reply.

Comment: That's not very helpful. Could you post the modified code? Also, how do you run it? Is it a function, part of another function, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query it will include all the results in a single query.

> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS id,GROUP_CONCAT(post_id) AS post_id,GROUP_CONCAT(comment) AS comment,GROUP_CONCAT(replyTo) AS replyTo
>   FROM comment WHERE post_id=17   GROUP BY replyTo ORDER BY id DESC

The result will look like

```
id    post_id   comment      replyTo

3      17           great           1

2,4    17,17        goodbye,bad    0,0

0,1    17,17        Blah,hello     2,2
```

I am not clear about your requirement.So it is just a suggestion...

Comment: Thank you! Would I apply this same query to the inner loop as well?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT distinct(comment),id,replyTo FROM comment WHERE post_id='$post_id' ORDER BY id DESC");

while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments))
{
    $id = $comment['id'];

    $comment = $comment['comment'];

    $reply = $comment['replyTo'];

    echo $comment;

    echo "<br />";


    $replyQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE replyTo='$id' and comment <>  '$comment' ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments))

    {

        $id = $comment['id'];

        $comment = $comment['comment'];

        $reply = $comment['replyTo'];

        echo $comment;

        echo "<br />";

     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With this I don't get my desired result

Comment: Please check it again i edited it.I hope it will return desire result